# Context local labels within GNU assembler macroses. Is it possible?

Tags: macros, gnu-assembler

Is it possible to get value from GAS .set-symbol to generate unique context local labels into macroses?
For example, the following pair of macroses generate pair of labels "for_label_$for_item" and "end_for_label_$for_item":

```
                .set            for_item, 0             # for-context counter

        .macro for counter
                .set            for_item, for_item + 1
                push            $\counter
                incq            (%rsp)                  # dec-compencation
            for_label_$for_item\():                     # for-context local label
                decq            (%rsp)                  # for-counter -= 1
                jnz             1f                      # start/continue if for-counter is not zero
                jmp             end_for_label_$for_item # no any iteration is needed
            1:                                          # next iteration
        .endm

        .macro end_for
                jmp             for_label_$for_item     # check for the next iteration
            end_for_label_$for_item:                    # for-context local label
                sub             $8, %rsp                # pop for-counter from stack
                .set            for_item, for_item - 1
        .endm
```

I mean "$for_item" symbol has to be substituted with its value which is unique for the each pairs of the for/end_for macroses. Unfortunately it is not worked as expectred: GAS generate labels as constants "for_label_$for_item"/"end_for_label_$for_item" without substitution for_item symbol with its value. The second or nested use for/end_for macroses caused messages like "Error: symbol `for_label_$for_item' is already defined".

I have checked many variants like "\for_item", "(for_item)", "@for_item" and so on without success. Seems, GAS is restricted for such constructions unlike other assemblers (nasm, etc), isn't it?

Comment: You can generate a unique number with `\@`. See the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html), bottom of page. There is also `LOCAL` if you enable `.altmacro`.

Comment: I know about \@ very well. It is common counter for each macros call. Unfortunately it is looked like absolutely useless for label which is created in any other macro. For example, how can I write instruction "jmp end_for_label_\@" (which will be expanded to "jmp end_for_label_1" ) in "for" macro call in the first time, but label is defined and will be expanded to "end_for_label_2" in the "end_for" macro call in the second time?

Comment: Ah yeah I missed that you wanted to share it between macros.